# Predictive Modeling Birth Count Data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I was given this data (below) and I want to try some predictive modeling with the data. Specifically, I want to build a linear regression to predict birth counts (by month, if possible) until the year 2032.

Would a poisson model be a good fit?

Here are my data

In wide format:

```
> dput(births_monthly_cross_022822_clean)
structure(list(month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
), `2010` = c(323816, 302551, 339219, 325582, 328960, 335180, 
345875, 350473, 351439, 337477, 326868, 339665), `2011` = c(321104, 
298537, 330752, 313875, 327242, 337890, 346192, 360079, 346254, 
329174, 322135, 327986), `2012` = c(316959, 305060, 324944, 307262, 
330779, 327811, 348157, 361902, 340901, 346251, 325810, 324960
), `2013` = c(324314, 292360, 321166, 312274, 330193, 320475, 
349920, 354293, 338863, 341353, 319233, 336320), `2014` = c(327154, 
299087, 324317, 319788, 335444, 326757, 356446, 355201, 349403, 
344265, 318819, 341494), `2015` = c(326747, 298815, 329714, 321618, 
328709, 331400, 354384, 352782, 348479, 339904, 319605, 336576
), `2016` = c(317445, 306750, 329341, 314312, 328434, 333166, 
343643, 358737, 346525, 331939, 320258, 325562), `2017` = c(314597, 
289694, 320327, 300801, 323169, 324633, 335708, 353033, 338012, 
330762, 317280, 316738), `2018` = c(315593, 284940, 316824, 299125, 
321448, 315585, 329851, 345687, 323685, 327740, 309475, 311581
), `2019` = c(311678, 280679, 304999, 299755, 317160, 304843, 
334518, 342617, 326662, 326165, 298899, 309607), `2020` = c(305536, 
283385, 302331, 290940, 301902, 302574, 322096, 320072, 312152, 
305548, 283010, 290280)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(month = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `2010` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2011` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2012` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2013` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2014` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2015` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2016` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2017` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2018` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2019` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2020` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Same data but in long format:

```
> dput(Birthcount)
structure(list(month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12), name = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
"2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", 
"2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
"2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", 
"2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
"2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"), value = c(323816, 
321104, 316959, 324314, 327154, 326747, 317445, 314597, 315593, 
311678, 305536, 302551, 298537, 305060, 292360, 299087, 298815, 
306750, 289694, 284940, 280679, 283385, 339219, 330752, 324944, 
321166, 324317, 329714, 329341, 320327, 316824, 304999, 302331, 
325582, 313875, 307262, 312274, 319788, 321618, 314312, 300801, 
299125, 299755, 290940, 328960, 327242, 330779, 330193, 335444, 
328709, 328434, 323169, 321448, 317160, 301902, 335180, 337890, 
327811, 320475, 326757, 331400, 333166, 324633, 315585, 304843, 
302574, 345875, 346192, 348157, 349920, 356446, 354384, 343643, 
335708, 329851, 334518, 322096, 350473, 360079, 361902, 354293, 
355201, 352782, 358737, 353033, 345687, 342617, 320072, 351439, 
346254, 340901, 338863, 349403, 348479, 346525, 338012, 323685, 
326662, 312152, 337477, 329174, 346251, 341353, 344265, 339904, 
331939, 330762, 327740, 326165, 305548, 326868, 322135, 325810, 
319233, 318819, 319605, 320258, 317280, 309475, 298899, 283010, 
339665, 327986, 324960, 336320, 341494, 336576, 325562, 316738, 
311581, 309607, 290280)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -132L))
```

Comment: Your data is just a time series of length 132. You could make it easier to interpret when you just plot the data along with a more lean format for the data.

Comment: A Poisson distribution for the data might be too restrictive. It is likely that the data/births are not independent. For instance, in a given population you have people/couples that are trying to get a kid (or a few more) and keep trying untill they reach their desired family size. This makes that the number of births is not like a random Poisson process, instead there is some family planning behind it. We are not monkeys or rabbits that just keep on reproducing ad infinitum (no offence to the rabbits and monkeys).

Comment: In addition, variations in births are not just due to the dice rolling type of Poisson process. Instead there are variations that make births behave with much more variations. The 'steady state' variation among the births in the period from 2010 to 2020 might be a bad indicator for the error/uncertainty in predictions of births between 2020 and 2032.

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus It's actually more complex than "steady state" as the number of births decreases quite quickly from 2016 onwards. Extrapolating this trend for 10 years could lead to something surprising like births declining by 50% in a decade. So the best advice is to not model this data at all?

Comment: @dipetkov One might still be able to model the data but not with a straight line.